# PHP Arrays : echo a range of ID

Tags: php, html, arrays, php-5.3

i've a problem when displaying some product in a page,
The products must be arranged by category, with the IDs 101 to 199 are displayed together, as others, IDs 201-299 must be arranged in another div so different category.

Here is a cut of my code:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="wrapper">

<ul class="products"> 
    <?php foreach /*Product IDs 101-199 */
        ($products as $product_id => $product) {
        echo "<li>";    
        echo '<a href="item.php?id=' . $product_id . '">';
        echo '<img src="' . $product["img"] . '"" alt="' . $product["name"] . '" class="imgres">';      
        echo '<p id="det">Dettagli</p>';
        echo "</a>";
        echo "</li>";
 } ?>

</ul>
<ul class="products2">

    <?php /* Here goes the 201-299 items */ 


    ?>  

</ul>
```

The array file is in an include dir, listing name, images and details.

IDs start from 101 to 199 for first product category, and 201 to 299 for second category items.

Here is the corrected code, that show the items not correctly.

```
<?php foreach                                                               /*Product IDs 101-199 */
        ($products as $product_id => $product) {
            if ($product_id >= 101 || $product_id <= 199 ) {
                echo '<ul class="products">';
                echo "<li>";    
                echo '<a href="item.php?id=' . $product_id . '">';
                echo '<img src="' . $product["img"] . '"" alt="' . $product["name"] . '" class="imgres">';      
                echo '<p id="det">Dettagli</p>';
                echo "</a>";
                echo "</li>";
                echo '</ul>';
            }
            elseif ($product_id >= 201 || $product_id <= 299) {                 /*Product IDs 201-299 */
                echo '<br>';
                echo '<ul class="products2">';      
                echo "<li>";    
                echo '<a href="item.php?id=' . $product_id . '">';
                echo '<img src="' . $product["img"] . '"" alt="' . $product["name"] . '" class="imgres2">';     
                echo '<p id="det">Dettagli</p>';
                echo "</a>";
                echo "</li>";
                echo '</ul>';
            }
                 } ?>
```

Here is the product array file:

```
    <?php $products = array();
$products[101] = array (
    "name" => "Lusso",
    "art" => "02",
    "weight" => "110 g",
    "size" => "45x70",
    "img" => "img/prod/lux1.png",
    "desc" => "Strofinaccio a composizione non determinata (DL. 883/79)",
);
$products[102] = array (
    "name" => "Fatto",
    "art" => "08",
    "weight" => "130 g",
    "size" => "45x65",
    "img" => "img/prod/fat1.png",
    "desc" => "Strofinaccio a composizione non determinata (DL. 883/79)",
);
$products[103] = array (
    "name" => "Rigati",
    "art" => "04",
    "weight" => "80 g",
    "size" => "45x65",
    "img" => "img/prod/rig1.png",
    "desc" => "Strofinaccio a composizione non determinata (DL. 883/79)",
);
$products[104] = array (
    "name" => "Giganti",
    "art" => "05",
    "weight" => "150 g",
    "size" => "45x90",
    "img" => "img/prod/gig1.png",
    "desc" => "Strofinaccio a composizione non determinata (DL. 883/79)",
);

$products[105] = array (
    "name" => "Bandiera",
    "art" => "20",
    "weight" => "120 g",
    "size" => "45x75",
    "img" => "img/prod/ban1.png",
    "desc" => "Strofinaccio a composizione non determinata (DL. 883/79)",
);

$products[106] = array (
    "name" => "Scozzesi",
    "art" => "12",
    "weight" => "90 g",
    "size" => "45x65",
    "img" => "img/prod/sco1.png",
    "desc" => "Strofinaccio a composizione non determinata (DL. 883/79)",
);

/* FILATI */
/*$products2 = array();*/

$products[201] = array (
    "name" => "Filato Super Candido",
    "art" => "50",
    "weight" => "10 g/m",
    "size" => "50pz +",
    "img" => "img/prod/scd1.png",
    "desc" => "Filato a composizione non determinata (DL. 883/79)",
);

$products[202] = array (
    "name" => "Filato Rossino",
    "art" => "50",
    "weight" => "10 g/m",
    "size" => "50pz +",
    "img" => "img/prod/scd1.png",
    "desc" => "Filato a composizione non determinata (DL. 883/79)",
);
 ?>
```

Comment: So what is your actual question? Whats not working for you? what did you try?

Comment: the items now are showed all together, so i must to provide a code to show these range of id in the "products" div and a second range of IDs in a second div called "products2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two different array / object for both sections. You can follow this code :

```
<?php 

$firstArray = array();
$secondArray = array();
foreach ($products as $product_id => $product) {
if($product_id >=101 || $product_id <= 199)
{
     $firstArray[$product_id] = $product;
}
else if($product_id >= 201 || $product_id <= 299 )
{
     $secondArray[$product_id] = $product;
}

 ?>
```

Now you can display the $firstArray in products div and $secondArray in products2 div.

```
<ul class="products">
<?php foreach($firstArray as $product_id => $product) {
        echo "<li>";    
        echo '<a href="item.php?id=' . $product_id . '">';
        echo '<img src="' . $product["img"] . '"" alt="' . $product["name"] . '" class="imgres">';      
        echo '<p id="det">Dettagli</p>';
        echo "</a>";
        echo "</li>";
} ?>
</ul>

<ul class="products2">
<?php foreach($secondArray as $product_id => $product) {
        echo "<li>";    
        echo '<a href="item.php?id=' . $product_id . '">';
        echo '<img src="' . $product["img"] . '"" alt="' . $product["name"] . '" class="imgres">';      
        echo '<p id="det">Dettagli</p>';
        echo "</a>";
        echo "</li>";
} ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank You, the code provided works, i don't know if is an error but it show all the items inline, even if i've set another class for the div.

I will update the first post whit current code.

Comment: can you post your current loop ?

Comment: did you think the array file? i've updated in the answer

Comment: ok, i've replace my code with the code you provide, but " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in ***\*****\products.php on line 52 ( @line 52 i have </body> tag ) so i think there is a semicolon opened? i can't see the error...

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="products"> 
    <?php foreach($products as $product_id => $product):

        if($product_id > 200): ?>

           </ul>
           <ul class="products2">

        <?php endif;?>

        <li>   
        <a href="item.php?id=<?php echo $product_id;?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $product["img"];?>" alt="<?php echo $product["name"];?>" class="imgres">   
            <p id="det">Dettagli</p>
        </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach;?>

</ul>
```